# javax.naming.NameNotFoundException in Jetty but not in Tomcat. How to solve?

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, jetty, jndi

I have a sample code like this:

```
ConnectionPool.dataSource = (DataSource) initialContext.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/murach");
```

and in **webapp/META-INF/context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>
<Resource name="jdbc/murach"
          auth="Container"
          type="javax.sql.DataSource"
          username="root"
          --- Rest of the text ---/>
</Context>
```

When I deploy this web app to Tomcat, DB connection is fine, however when I try with Jetty using Jetty Plugin in with: **jetty:run-war**

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>9.2.1.v20140609</version>
    <configuration>
        <scanIntervalSeconds>2</scanIntervalSeconds>
        <httpConnector>
            <port>8082</port>
        </httpConnector>
        <webApp>
            <contextPath>/</contextPath>
        </webApp>
    </configuration> 
 </plugin>
```

I am getting:

```
 javax.naming.NameNotFoundException; remaining name 'jdbc/murach'
```

How can I make this work with jetty as well?

I also tried adding

```
<resource-ref>
    <description>murach</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/murach</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

to web.xml, but now I am getting:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Nothing to bind for name javax.sql.DataSource/default
```

Comment: is this datasource defined for your Jetty server ? [https://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Configure_JNDI_Datasource](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Configure_JNDI_Datasource)

Comment: @Koray Tugay See m.hassaballah's answer below. You be defining your datasource in your web.xml file as a resource, not just in Context.xml.

Comment: Just want to know... Was my answer helpful or are there some problems to use suggested approach?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Jetty should be configured to use JNDI and deploy JNDI resource into it.

Try to add to maven plugin configuration:

```
<configuration>
   <!-- ... -->
   <jettyEnvXml>src/main/dev-path-to-jetty-env-xml/jetty-env.xml</jettyEnvXml>
   <webXml>src/main/dev-path-to-web-xml/web.xml</webXml>
</configuration>
```

The file `jetty-env.xml` looks like (only as example; used bonecp datasource):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure.dtd">
<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
    <New id="murachDataSource" class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource">
        <Arg>jdbc/murach</Arg>

        <Arg>
            <New class="com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource">
                <Set name="driverClass">org.h2.Driver</Set>
                <Set name="jdbcUrl">jdbc:h2:~/murach/test</Set>
                <Set name="username">sa</Set>
                <Set name="password"/>

                <Set name="partitionCount">4</Set>
                <Set name="minConnectionsPerPartition">5</Set>
                <Set name="acquireIncrement">5</Set>
                <Set name="closeConnectionWatch">false</Set>
            </New>
        </Arg>
    </New>
</Configure>
```

File `web.xml` should contain lines:

```
<resource-ref>
    <description>My DataSource Reference</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/murach</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

Answer (score 4):

i wanted to add this as a comment, it's not allowed to me yet.
**svaor**'s answer is the correct one, because there is not a standard place defined to put JNDI resources in J2EE specification.
So, context.xml file is tomcat specific, and jetty don't know anything about it.

http://docs.jboss.org/jbossweb/3.0.x/jndi-resources-howto.html

> The J2EE standard provides a standard set of elements in the
>   /WEB-INF/web.xml file to reference resources; resources referenced in
>   these elements must be defined in an application-server-specific
>   configuration.

Answer (score 3):

Did you add resource-ref to web.xml?

```
 <resource-ref>
    <description>XX</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/murach</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
  </resource-ref>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I am getting: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Nothing to bind for name javax.sql.DataSource/default